Fixed Position for 3D Model on ImageTarget with Vuforia
I am developing an AR application, with Vuforia ImageTarget I added a QR code to be scanned. When scan the qr code I want my 3d model appear with fixed point and scale on the screen and do not track ImageTarget anymore.
Default Observer Event Handler script at Vuforia Package has 3 options which Tracked, Tracked or Extended Tracked and Tracked,Extenden Tracked or Limited but non of these options are not satisfy what I want. I just want to scan QR code once the model should appears on screen with fixed point and scale then 3d model should not track ImageTarget anymore. Also I read Vuforia Images&Objects Library but can not find a useful tip.

To clarify, do you want 1. the model to stay at the same location in physical space, meaning right where the qr code is but just stop tracking or 2. the model to stay on the screen of the user, meaning always in view?

The second one, model stay on the screen of the user thus in the application I want user can see the model on their screen while they are handling the setup guides steps or errors occur on machine and apply solution steps. So they can make any manipulation on device while they can see model on their screen easily.

First of all thanks to all who contribute to solve this problem. With help of @charanvendra I revise the code and finally solve the problem. For those who is faced with similar problems like I do the code :
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class QRTrackerHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ObserverBehaviour mObserverBehaviour;
    private bool isModelDisplayed = false;

    public GameObject model;  // Assign 3D model in the inspector

    private GameObject modelContainer; // Create a container which positioned according to camera

    void Start()
    {
        mObserverBehaviour = GetComponent<ObserverBehaviour>();
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnTargetStatusChanged;
        }

        if (model != null)
        {
            model.SetActive(false);  // Initially hide the model
            CreateModelContainer();
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged -= OnTargetStatusChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnTargetStatusChanged(ObserverBehaviour behaviour, TargetStatus targetStatus)
    {
        if (!isModelDisplayed && (targetStatus.Status == Status.TRACKED ||
                                  targetStatus.Status == Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED))
        {
            DisplayModel();
            isModelDisplayed = true;
            DisableTracking();
        }
    }

    private void CreateModelContainer()
    {
        modelContainer = new GameObject("ModelContainer");
        modelContainer.transform.SetParent(Camera.main.transform);
        modelContainer.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 275);  // Adjust the Z value as needed
        modelContainer.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(-90, 0, 0); // RotateModel to show as needed
        modelContainer.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        model.transform.SetParent(modelContainer.transform);
        model.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
        model.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        model.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
    }

    private void DisplayModel()
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            model.SetActive(true);  // Show the model
        }
    }

    private void DisableTracking()
    {
        if (mObserverBehaviour)
        {
            mObserverBehaviour.OnTargetStatusChanged -= OnTargetStatusChanged;
        }
    }
}

Do not need to use System.Collections;

You can do it like this:
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class QRTrackerHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    private bool isModelDisplayed = false;

    public GameObject model;  // Assign your 3D model in the inspector

    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterOnTrackableStatusChanged(OnTrackableStatusChanged);
        }

        if (model != null)
        {
            model.SetActive(false);  // Initially hide the model
        }
    }

    private void OnTrackableStatusChanged(TrackableBehaviour.StatusChangeResult statusChangeResult)
    {
        if (!isModelDisplayed && (statusChangeResult.NewStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
                                  statusChangeResult.NewStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
                                  statusChangeResult.NewStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED))
        {
            DisplayModel();
            isModelDisplayed = true;
            DisableTracking();
        }
    }

    private void DisplayModel()
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            model.transform.parent = null; // you may omit this depending on your need
            model.SetActive(true);  // Show the model
        }
    }

    private void DisableTracking()
    {
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.UnregisterOnTrackableStatusChanged(OnTrackableStatusChanged);
        }
    }
}


model.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);             model.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); I don't think you would want to include these! As I understand the question the model should appear with the transformation of the tracked image target .. but then stay there so why would you reset the position and scale?

you are right, my bad, let me remove those lines.

Should I assign this script into ImageTarget as a component and remove Default Observer Event Handler comes with Vuforia or edit the initial script and change with this one you shared ?

Also when I try to create a new script as QRTrackerHandler there is an error occurs like "CS0103: The name 'TrackableBehaviour' does not exist in the current context" . I do not know why even I include using Vuforia;

@Zulh, The TrackableBehaviour base class has been deprecated and replaced with the ObserverBehaviour
